# prove that $x^2 \geq{0}$ using only axioms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, inequality

The question asks you to prove that $ 0 \leq{x^2} $ using only the following axioms and basic addition and multiplication properties distinct from inequalities.

1)$a \leq{a}$ 
 2)$a \leq{b}$ and $b \leq{a}$ $\implies$ $a=b$ 
 3) $a \leq{b}$ and  $b \leq{c}$ $\implies$  $a \leq{c}$ 
 4) $a \leq{b}$ $\implies$ $a+c \leq{b+c}$ 
 5)$a \leq{b}$ and $0 \leq{c}$ $\implies$ $ac \leq{bc}$  
the questions then follow to ask why does $n \leq{n+1}$ which I can show on the basis of this propostion which I can't for some reason find any way to show. Any hints or solutions are welcome. 
 
 the question is from Discrete Mathematics by Norman L.Biggs

Comment: For $x^2\geq 0$, You first want to show that if $x>0$ then $-x<0$. Then split into two cases and use 5). For $n\leq n+1$, use 4).

Comment: I am trying to avoid using x>0 or x< 0 though because I feel as though that isn't suggested by the axioms

Comment: It is an axiom that for all (real or rational) $x,$ exactly one of three things must be true: $x< 0 $ or $x>0$ or $x=0$. So you have three cases to consider.

Comment: I am still doubtful because it's not a property directly stated by the axioms in the question. Is there any other way to show it

Comment: One needs to add something to the list: 6) $a^2=a\cdot a$, 7) $a\cdot 0=0$, 8) $a+0=a$, 9) $a+(-a)=0$, 10) $a\leq b \lor b \leq a$.

Comment: If you exclude axiom 10, then $0\leq a^2$ can be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

If $x\ge0:$

$5)$ $0 \le x$ and $0 \le x$ $\implies$ $0*x \le x*x\implies 0\le x^2$

---

If $x\le0 :$

$4)$ $x+(-x)\le 0 + (-x) \implies 0\le -x$

$5)$ $0\le -x$ and $0\le-x \implies 0*(-x)\le(-x)*(-x) \implies 0\le x^2$